# Unable to install Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm, ubuntu-16.04

I just upgraded my system to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (clean install) and tried to install Ruby using RVM. RVM itself installs fine (using this guide http://www.webupd8.org/2014/11/how-to-install-rvm-ruby-version-manager.html), but when I then try to install Ruby I get the following error:

```
user@user:~$ rvm install 2.3.0
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.  
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/16.04/x86_64/ruby-2.3.0.  
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for ubuntu.  
Requirements installation successful.  
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...  
ruby-2.3.0 - #downloading ruby-2.3.0, this may take a while depending on your connection...  
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed  
     0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0  
Warning: Failed to create the file ruby-2.3.0.tar.bz2.part: Permission denied  
0 13.5M    0 16384    0     0  19826      0  0:11:55 --:--:--  0:11:55 19811  
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16384)  
There was an error(23).  
Checking fallback: https://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.3/ruby-2.3.0.tar.bz2
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
     0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0
Warning: Failed to create the file ruby-2.3.0.tar.bz2.part: Permission denied  
     0 13.5M    0 16149    0     0   7324      0  0:32:16  0:00:02  0:32:14  7323  
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16149)  
There was an error(23).  
Failed download  
There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

Is that a general problem for 16.04? The exact method worked fine under 15.10. Any ideas how this can be fixed?

Comment: In my case, it was caused by `rvm_path` set to local path. For more info, try this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/440584/253876

Comment: Some occasions, after the rvm installation it's necessary reboot your system. Here I had this problem and did it and solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install [`rvm`](https://rvm.io/) **without** sudo privileges, everything else should work as expected

If you have rvm installed, remove it using

```
rvm implode
```

or

```
rm -rf ~/.rvm
```

Then install rvm using

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Then install ruby with

```
rvm install 2.3.0
```

Use whichever version you wanna install.

Now go ahead and install rails

```
gem install rails
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like rvm is trying to install the Ruby to /usr/share/rvm, which I think means that it's being installed at the system-wide level rather than the user level.  Is that what you wanted?  That being the case, it may be necessary to run rvm as sudo:

```
user@user:~$ sudo rvm install 2.3.0
```

For what it's worth, I install rvm as me (my user) so that I don't have to mess with privileges; and I'm the only user on the system that needs rvm.

Comment: Thx for your quick response. I have previously tried this and it gives me the following error: `sudo: rvm: command not found`

Comment: Did you want to install it as system or user?

Comment: On user level would probably make more sense as you mentioned, although I'm the only user on the system.

Comment: Then I suggest reinstalling rvm as your user.

Comment: You being the only user on the system is an argument *for* installing it as your user rather than system.  If there were multiple users, you'd have multiple copies of the rubies and gems taking up space.  I have been installing rvm as my user for years on hosts where I am the only user.  My life is way easier than if I had installed it as system.  Try it, you'll like it. ;)

Comment: @KeithBennett I curl installed rvm as user and get this same error as OP.

Comment: @earth2jason You got "Permission denied" errors?  Is it trying to install to /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0?  (If it is, then, it's being installed as system and not user.  You need to be logged in as a user other than root, the user that will be running the Ruby.) You could try curl installing rvm without any Rubies and then try installing a different version of Ruby to see if the problem is version-specific.

Comment: @KeithBennet I was using a alternate user. I have resigned to just using the ubuntu user that was pre-configured in my linux container and it works fine. So I am good with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try a reboot.

I had the same problem with two installs of Ubuntu 16.04 
Both computers had the same problem, it was fixed after I rebooted.

```
rvm install ruby-2.5.0
```